# CSS, "-webkit-animation" consumes too much CPU on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the following CSS:

```
.navbar .agesbar {
        height: 55px;
        background-image: url('/img/nicebar.jpg');
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;

        width: 100%;
        -webkit-animation: agesTicker 120s linear infinite;
        animation: agesTicker 120s linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes agesTicker {
        from {background-position: 0 0;}
        to {background-position: -2446px 0;}
    }       
    @keyframes agesTicker {
        from {background-position: 0 0;}
        to {background-position: -2446px 0;}
    }
```

Everything works fine, unfortunately, it consumes too much CPU on Google Chrome. (10-20%). On Firefox, and even Internet Explorer it doesn't waste that much CPU (only 2-3%).
I fixed the high CPU usage by adding:

```
will-change: transform;
```

to force gpu acceleration, unfortunately it doesn't fix the performance, because now the GPU is "working heavier": The laptop is getting warmer and the fan in my laptop is getting a bit louder.

I've got two questions: 1. Why this animation works so bad on Chrome, while it's fine on the other browsers? 2. Is there any replacement to this animation, for example a jquery script?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use CSS `transition` and than just change background position using js/jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').css({'background-position': '0px -200px'});
});
```

```css
.test {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/') no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: background-position 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Unfortunately, it also works slow. The CPU usage is even higher (20% all the time), and also ~10% on Firefox :(

Comment: @Przmus I hope you turned off old code. Also have you tried other computer? Because I see no issues. Does this test also increase CPU usage?

Comment: You're right. That's strange, but this code works fine here (using the normal -webkit-animation): https://jsfiddle.net/z6b5cvxm/
I have no idea why it has so high usage CPU on my site, and only with Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

my guess it the problem is due to `background-size: cover`, as far as I remember resized image is not cached so browser has to recalculate it everytime

try to remove it and see it anything changes

Answer (score 0):

I guess `background-position` animation is slow. Maybe animation with `translate`will be faster?